# How can I fit the model “Y(t) = αX + βY(t-1) - βY(t-2)" in R?

Tags: r, time-series, regression, forecasting, autoregressive-models

I have to make a one-step ahead forecast for a time series *Y(t)* using R. Theory suggests the ideal model should be:

*Y(t) = αX + βY(t-1) - βY(t-2)*

However, I don't know how to deal with the following issues:

- I have to take *βY(t-1)* **minus** *βY(t-2)*.
- There are both **autoregressive** (*Y(t-1)*,*Y(t-2)*) and **exogenous** variables (*X*).
- I have to test whether or not "*βY(t-1) - βY(t-2)*" is the best way to express the autoregression, instead of other ARIMA models.

The time series *Y(t)* in question is:

```
Y <- c(57.4, 51.6, 36.1, 34.8, 41.2, 59.1, 62.5, 55.0, 53.8, 52.4, 44.5, 42.2, 50.1, 61.3, 49.6, 38.2, 51.1, 44.7, 40.8, 46.1, 53.5, 54.7, 50.3, 48.8, 53.7, 52.0)
```

The exogenous variable *X* used is:

```
X <- c(-12.1, 30.0, 13.5, 30.0, -3.8, -24.3, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, -21.6, 30.0, 0.0, 26.5, -30.0, 20.5, -4.8, -9.2, 22.2, -7.3, 15.9, 16.0, 13.7, 5.6, 5.7, 1.8)
```

As you may notice, this actual X does not provide much help in predicting Y. Nevertheless, I reported it as an example since I am currently looking for the right values of X.

If anything was wrong or not clear, let me know and I will give the necessary explanations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `lag` function for the transformation and `lm` or `glm` for regression:

```
Y <- c(57.4, 51.6, 36.1, 34.8, 41.2, 59.1, 62.5, 55.0, 53.8, 52.4, 44.5, 42.2, 50.1, 61.3, 49.6, 38.2, 51.1, 44.7, 40.8, 46.1, 53.5, 54.7, 50.3, 48.8, 53.7, 52.0)
X <- c(-12.1, 30.0, 13.5, 30.0, -3.8, -24.3, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 30.0, -21.6, 30.0, 0.0, 26.5, -30.0, 20.5, -4.8, -9.2, 22.2, -7.3, 15.9, 16.0, 13.7, 5.6, 5.7, 1.8)

y_1 <- lag(Y)
y_2 <- lag(Y,2)

lm(Y~X+y_1+y_2)
```

You could also do the lag transformations directly in the regression equation:

```
lm(Y ~ X + I(lag(Y)) + I(lag(Y, 2)))
```

Finally, the difference is just a change of the operator to this:

```
lm(Y ~ X + I(lag(Y)) - I(lag(Y, 2)))
```

> ```
> Call:
> lm(formula = Y ~ X + I(lag(Y)) - I(lag(Y, 2)))
>
> Coefficients:
> (Intercept)            X    I(lag(Y))  
>   3.906e-14   -4.693e-18    1.000e+00
> ```

Comment: It is almost complete, however I have to test it against other models such as _ARIMA(0,0,2)_, etc. The function 'auto.arima()' suggested me an _ARIMA(0,0,1)_. How can I compare this model "... + Y(t-1) - Y(t-1)" against an _ARIMA(0,0,1)_?

Comment: @smars Compare it in what way? You can run predictions with `predict` and calculate validation statistics from that or using `Metrics` if that's what you mean. This is just a direct answer to the question you asked regarding how to estimate the specified model.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will eventually post another question related to that.