# Is there a shorter way to use Lag Operators in a Regression in R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to replicate a regression that I saw in an article:

`Y_t=a(L) Y_(t-1)`

Where `L` is a polynomial in the lag operator and it said that

> “Lag dependent variable [Lags: 1-24] is entered as four-quarter moving
>   average for lags 1, 5, 9, 13, 17 and 21, respectively”.

[I saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471043/how-can-i-fit-the-model-yt-%CE%B1x-%CE%B2yt-1-%CE%B2yt-2-in-r/40471087#40471087) that I can do something like this:

`lm(Y ~ I(lag(Y)) + I(lag(Y, 5)) + I(lag(Y, 9)) + I(lag(Y, 13)) + I(lag(Y, 17)) + I(lag(Y, 21)) + I(lag(Y, 24))`

Is there a shorter way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe?

```
lags <- c(1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21)
xnam <- paste0("I(lag(Y, ", lags, "))")
(fmla <- as.formula(paste("y ~ ", paste(xnam, collapse= "+"))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Unfortunately, I tried a regression with other variables and it was not possible.
The following message appeared: "Error in model.frame.default (formula = y ~ x +: invalid type (language) for variable 'fmla'".

Comment: I think you should maybe then ask a new question, asking specifically about the lag function, and the regression, with a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - you're more likely to get an answer. I thought that your main problem was just shortening the formula, as stated in the title.

Comment: Thanks again. Just now I understood better the regression I wanted to do. I'll even delete my previous comment. I'll stay only trying to solve the error when making the shorter version of the formula.